# How I can implement correctly getPosts from Dataservice in angular Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am using Ionic version 4 and trying to implement services and external data. But method `getPosts()` is not recognized. I restarted the server the problem continues. What happened?

PostComponents.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.dataService.getPost()
 .subscribe((posts: any[])=>{
   console.log(posts);
   this.mensajes= posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported your dataService to your components before making use of it because I cannot see that here.

Also you said you were trying to call getposts but what I see you calling here is getPost()

Comment: thanks for your response. I already  solved this issue. I supossed that I implemented the method getposts() inside dataservice file but the file didn't get saved. Thats why the method getPosts() was not called correctly from PostComponents file. Thanks